# PHP pspell_check returns always FALSE

Tags: php, passwords, password-protection, spell-checking, pspell

I want to use *pspell_check* to determine the complexity of passwords chosen by users. The problem is that my code, inspired by the [basic examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-check.php) available on the web, always returns *FALSE*. Example code:

```
$pspell_link = pspell_new('en');
echo (int)pspell_check($pspell_link, 'correct');
echo (int)pspell_check($pspell_link, 'wrongsishly');
```

What might be wrong in my setting?